# What's the relationship between Yeoman's generator-webapp and generator-angular?

Tags: angularjs, npm, yeoman, yeoman-generator

Does `generator-angular` always depend on installing `generator-webapp` first? I don't see `generator-webapp` in `generator-angular's` [dependencies](https://www.npmjs.org/package/generator-angular), yet on the [Yeoman front page](http://yeoman.io/) it did say running `npm install -g generator-webapp` before `npm install -g generator-angular`? What happens if I don't run `npm install -g generator-webapp`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does generator-angular always depend on installing generator-webapp first?

Nope, these are two separate generators. If you want to make a generic "webapp", you would use the webapp generator. If you want to make an Angular app, use `generator-angular`.

Can you point to the specific area of the website that tripped you up? We're always looking to improve the docs.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I did trip up on not doing "npm install" and having grunt being not found, I [brought it up](https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/issues/1289), but I guess it's not important as they closed the issue soon after.